# How to pass from a react props to a sass variable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

I am using React and SASS, and I got a cube component, and I want to render it with a dynamic width. However, I am operating on this width in my .scss. There is an example.

My component:

```
<Cube style={{ width: '100px' }} />
<Cube style={{ width: '70px' }} />
<Cube style={{ width: '20px' }} />
```

My style.scss:

```
$cubeWidth: 150px;
$cubeHeight: $cubeWidth;
#cube {
      width: $cubeWidth;
      height: $cubeHeight;
}

// In this cube, I have -of course- 6 faces, and I operate in my style.scss:

.cubeFace1 {
     transform: translateZ($cubeWidth / 2);
}
... etc
```

How is it possible to get my $cubeWidth equal to my dynamic width ?
Furthermore, .scss is loaded in index.js as follow:

```
// React index.js

import './css/style.scss';

render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass from react props to a sass variable. However, you can use styled-components: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation

1. `npm i styled-components`
2. In your Cube component code, add at the top, after the import statements,

```
const Cube = styled.div`
      width: props.cubeWidth;
      height: props.cubeHeight;
`;

const CubeFaceOne = styled.span`
      transform: translateZ(props.cubeWidth / 2);
`;
```

Using this approach, Cube and CubeFace will need to be split into two separate components, and will be rendered in something of this form,

```
render() {
  return (
    <Cube>
      <CubeFaceOne />
      <CubeFace />
      <CubeFace />
      ...
    </Cube>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't actually need it in SASS itself (for use in *server-side* pre-processing *before* the final CSS is generated), and you can simply pass the value over to final CSS **(client-side)**.

If you need the dynamic value in the final CSS, you can make use of CSS variables to do this. (This is a *pure* CSS feature, but since SASS and SCSS compile to CSS, we can use it.)

In a functional React component, you can use the effect hook to set a variable dynamically to the root:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  /* Note:
  Instead of :root you can also set this on the highest parent of your cube
  as it will limit the scope of the variable to that element and its children.
  */

  document.querySelector(':root').style
    .setProperty('--cubeWidth', widthVar);

  // OR:

  const rootStyle = document.querySelector(':root').style;
  rootStyle.setProperty('--cubeWidth', widthVar);
  rootStyle.setProperty('--cubeHeight', heightVar);
},
// this array optimizes the effect to run only on changes:
[widthVar, heightVar]);
```

*For class-based React components, this can also be achieved with `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()`.*

Then in your CSS, SCSS or SASS file, use the **CSS variable** as normal:

```css
.cubeFace1 {
  transform: translateZ(calc(var(--cubeWidth, 150px) / 2));
}
```

*You can optionally provide a default, like the `150px` above. Note the use of CSS `calc` though.*